# Regex extract nth block between character

Tags: regex, tableau-api

i am confronted with the following scenario: 
I'll like to extract one block of numbers (random and unspecific length) after another that is separated with an underscore only through regex:

```
Example: 111_234_4123_2341

Select first: 111
Secondly : 234
thirdly: 4123
```

Could anyone help me out? Any help is appreciated!

Best Regards
P.

Comment: Can you not split on `_`

Comment: i also thought about splitting on _ but i was not able to proceed

Comment: i am using Tableau to illustrate a set of big data. Here i have a key column that i mentioned above.

Comment: What language/tool are you needing the regex for?  Please update the tags.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want a particular segment separated with a underscore _ character,
which is almost like split.
Its more than likely the regex engine used overwrites a group if it is quantified more than once.
You can take advantage of that with something like this:

`(?:(\d+)_?){n}`

Returns the second segment (`n'th`) of : 123_`456`_789

```
 (?:
      ( \d+ )                       # (1)
      _?
 ){2}
```

This regex has problems though.
It requires there be something between underscores in the segment or the regex won't match.

There is a way to do it where it doesn't require digits between the underscore,
but still requires at least n-1 underscore . 
This uses a lookahead assertion and capture buffer 2 as a flag .

`(?:(?!\2)(\d*)(?:_|$())){n}`

```
 (?:
      (?! \2 )
      ( \d* )                       # (1)
      (?:
           _
        |  $ 
           ( )                           # (2)
      )
 ){2}
```